# Eclipse is copying an empty application.properties to target/classes (spring boot)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, eclipse, spring-data-jpa

I'm facing a problem with this specific project, the resultant `target/classes/application.properties` is copied as an empty one when I update the `src/main/resources/application.properties`.

For this project I'm using two datasources/jpa configs, following the same format as the following:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { PJE_BPMN_PACKAGES }, entityManagerFactoryRef = PJE_BPMN_EMF, transactionManagerRef = PJE_BPMN_TM)
public class PjeBpmnDbConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = PJE_BPMN_DS)
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "pjebpmn.datasource")
    public DataSource createDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }


    @Bean(name = PJE_BPMN_EMF)
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "pjebpmn.jpa")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder entityManagerFactoryBuilder,
            @Qualifier(PJE_BPMN_DS) DataSource dataSource) {

        Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
        System.out.println(
                "lendo pjebpmn.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto do properties, e retornou: " + env.getProperty("pjebpmn.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto", "NADA"));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("pjebpmn.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto", "update"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("pjebpmn.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"));

        return entityManagerFactoryBuilder.dataSource(dataSource).packages(PJE_BPMN_PACKAGES).persistenceUnit(PJE_BPMN_DS).properties(properties)
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = PJE_BPMN_TM)
    public PlatformTransactionManager createTransactionManager(@Qualifier(PJE_BPMN_EMF) EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {

        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

In the pom.xml, I'm using the start.spring.io generated, with `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`, `spring-boot-starter-web`, `lombok`, `spring-boot-devtools`, `spring-boot-configuration-processor` and `postgresql` dependencis.

Whats wrong?

PS: I activated the `Eclipse > Preferences > Maven > Annotation Processing > "Experimental"` option, and the deactivated moments later.

Environment:

- Mac Os catalina
- Eclipse 2022-09
- Sprint boot 2.7.6

I've tried with no success:

- delete project from eclipse and eclipse files (.project, .settings, etc) and import as an "existing MVN project"
- remove lombok and spring-boot-configuration-processor from pom.xml

Comment: You mean to say there is data in application.properties file but showing empty in target/classes/application.properties?

Comment: Yes. completely empty `target/classes/application.properties` file.

Comment: what is your major problem ? Maven config or Eclipse ? 1. open a terminal , `mvn clean package`, then check `target/classes/application.properties` is ok or empty ? if ok, then maven config file is not the problem, do not modify maven config pom.xml, test 2. `mvn clean spring-boot:run`, 3. Eclipse , Maven -> Annotation Processing -> `Do not automatically configure/execute annotation processing from pom.xml` , In your project -> `Run as` -> `Maven build` -> goal: `package`.

Comment: @life888888, everything is fine when executing maven the app using maven commands. I think the problem in on Ecipse.

Comment: Try, Click Your Project, popup menu `Maven` -> `Update Project`,  `Update Maven Project` Window, default checkbox for all, but not `Offline`

Comment: Or `File` -> `Switch workspace`, use new workspace. try again, you already try **delete eclipse files (.project, .settings, .classpath etc) and import as an "existing MVN project"**

Comment: `Maven -> Update Project`, all the time :), almost an automatic action on my fingers. Tried.
`File -> Switch workspace` -> I need to do this every day to switch between personal and professional projects... so, tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A friend from work, Simão, help me to find the problem.

I don't know how or why but in Eclipse inside `Project properties` > `Java Build Path` > tab `Source` > *source folders on build path* > `project/src/main/resources`, the option *Excluded* was `Excluded: **`, where is supposed to be `Excluded: none`

[image: Excluded option]

I expected that the *application.properties* wasn't copied at all, instead of a empty copy of it.

Comment: i'm sorry i wasn't helpful.  I check my project/src/main/resources, the option Excluded was Excluded: `**` by default. But , I edit it to remove `**` , to `none`, and I run menu `Maven build`, it automatic change to Excluded: `**`, My Eclipse Version: 2022-09 (4.25.0),

Comment: This is annoying, but the "Excluded" remains none in my project

Comment: This works for me.    Does anyone know **why eclipse does this** ???